# (node:16686) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection-refused

While conencting mongoDb with application facing issue : "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017"

Tried Solutions :

1. Reinstalling mongoDb
2. Restarting the mongoDb service from control panel services.
3. Reinstalling the mongoose.

Code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = new express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var user = require('./model/user')
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
var router = express.Router();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userdb', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var users = [{ name: "Jane", age: 20 }, { name: "Mark", age: 40 }, { name: "Janefer", age: 40 }]
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))//converts it into obj

router.route('/users')
    .get((req, res) => {
        //fetch record from users collectiobn
        user.find({}, (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ msg: 'error in fetching data from DB' })
            }
            else {
                res.json(users)
            }
        })
        // res.json(users)
    })
    .post((req, res) => {

    })
app.use('/api', router)//middleware to direct all req 
app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on 3000")
})
```

Error screenshot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ1qV.png)

Comment: have you verified that the database exists using a mongo shell? also, is it a database without authentication?

Comment: Yes checked with mongo shell..There is "userdb" database is available along with user collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to check which port mongodb is using in your mongodb.conf
after that if you still are have problem you can run the command `ps aux | grep mongo` and post the result.

Comment: root@test1:~/user/temp/Node /Server# ps aux | grep mongo
root      9854  0.0  0.0  14428  1024 pts/43   S+   05:20   0:00 grep mongo

Comment: Checked the mongod.cfg file as well port is the same as above i.e 27017

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [localhost] use [127.0.0.1]. like this -
'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userdb'

Comment: Changed to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userdb. but 
Still Facing the same error.

Comment: restart the mongodb services.

Comment: Not working with restarting mongodb services as well.